# Do neutrinos not interact with any kind of photons?

Tags: photons, reflection, neutrinos, sun

If billions of neutrinos reach us from the Sun why there is no any reflection of photons emitted from Earth to be reflected from them?
Is this they are not interacting at all?

Comment: Maybe reading this will help http://www.sns.ias.edu/~jnb/Papers/Popular/Scientificamerican69/scientificamerican69.html

Comment: I think you count wrong but nevermind your figures is far more accurate than IceCube in Antarctica ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, neutrinos (and other fundamental particles with no electric charge) do not interact directly with photons. They can interact indirectly, by mediation of virtual charged particles, but such interaction is very weak and in most cases negligible.

Answer (score 1):

There is one kind of photons, as seen in the table of elementary particles. Neutrinos interact only with the weak force. To interact with the matter of the earth it needs higher order Feynman diagrams, which give  very small probability of interaction. So they are interacting, and [specially designed experiments](http://www.sns.ias.edu/~jnb/Papers/Popular/Scientificamerican69/scientificamerican69.html) can record the interactions, but not at the level of giving detectable to the eye radiation.